# How to get the consonants of a string? I'm new in c++

Tags: string, function, constants

I'm new in c++ and I have to find the consonants of a string. Whenever I run the program I get a different number. I believe it is also counting the spaces but I'm not sure. This is part of my code. I believe this is where the problem may be.

```
int Countconsonants(string arg)
{
    int i;
    int cons = 0;
    for (i = arg.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
    if (arg[i] != 'A' && arg[i] != 'a' && arg[i] != 'E' && arg[i] != 'e' && arg[i] != 'I'

        && arg[i] != 'i' && arg[i] != 'O' && arg[i] != 'o' && arg[i] != 'U' && arg[i] != 'u')
        cons++;
    }

    return cons;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is counting the white spaces. To avoid that, you can add a condition in your if statement: **!isspace(arg[i])**

```
int Countconsonants(string arg)
{
    int i;
    int cons = 0;
    for (i = arg.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
    if (!isspace(arg[i]) && arg[i] != 'A' && arg[i] != 'a' && arg[i] != 'E' && arg[i] != 'e' && arg[i] != 'I'

        && arg[i] != 'i' && arg[i] != 'O' && arg[i] != 'o' && arg[i] != 'U' && arg[i] != 'u')
        cons++;
    }

    return cons;
}
```